# In fuzzy logic, how can I add membership functions for different perspectives?

Tags: java, fuzzy-logic, jfuzzylogic

I am using jFuzzyLogic library for a FL project.

I have created a FCL file that has three variables, service, room and food.

```
FUZZIFY food
    TERM bad := (0, 1) (4, 0) ; 
    TERM good := (1, 0) (4,1) (6,1) (9,0);
    TERM excellent := (6, 0) (9, 1);
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY service
    TERM poor := (0, 1) (4, 0) ; 
    TERM good := (1, 0) (4,1) (6,1) (9,0);
    TERM excellent := (6, 0) (9, 1);
END_FUZZIFY

FUZZIFY room
    TERM poor := (0, 1) (4, 0) ; 
    TERM good := (1, 0) (4,1) (6,1) (9,0);
    TERM excellent := (6, 0) (9, 1);
END_FUZZIFY
```

I also have two rules (these are not exhaustive) that are :

```
RULEBLOCK rules
    AND : MIN;          // Use 'min' for 'and' (also implicit use 'max' for 'or' to fulfill DeMorgan's Law)
    ACT : MIN;          // Use 'min' activation method
    ACCU : MAX;         // Use 'max' accumulation method

    RULE 1 : IF food IS bad OR service IS poor OR room IS poor THEN trustWeight IS less;
    RULE 2 : IF food IS excellent OR service IS excellent OR room IS excellent THEN trustWeight IS high;

END_RULEBLOCK
```

The final output is of the following set:

```
DEFUZZIFY trustWeight
    TERM less := (0,0) (0.25,1) (0.5,0);
    TERM high := (0.5,0) (0.75,1) (1,0);
    METHOD : COG;       // Use 'Center Of Gravity' defuzzification method
    DEFAULT := 0;       // Default value is 0 (if no rule activates defuzzifier)
END_DEFUZZIFY
```

My logic is that based on the input from different types of people, different weights should be allocated. For example when a businessman rates a room(5/10) and a familyman rates a room(5/10), the output shouldn't be the same
I need to be able to have rules that's like the following:

- If its a familyman, and the room is bad then trustWeight is less
- If its a businessman, and the room is bad then the trustWeight is high

Based on the type of person (and other fixed factors) I should be able to get differentTrustWeight results.

Is this possible to be done? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I would add another input person:

```
FUZZIFY person
  TERM family := 1;
  TERM business := 2;
END_FUZZIFY
```

and the necessary rules:

```
RULE 3 : IF person IS business THEN trustWeight IS high;
RULE 4 : IF person IS family THEN trustWeight IS less;
```